# What is 'obj' while creating custom list_display in the Django ModelAdmin

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

While going through the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) for a **custom list_display** (displaying fields in the admin, other than the fields present in the model), I came through the below code:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('upper_case_name',)

    @admin.display(description='Name')
    def upper_case_name(self, obj):
        return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
```

The `PersonAdmin` class is the `self` in the method `upper_case_name`, but I wonder what is the `obj` here? And how does this object get passed into this method?

Comment: It's an instance of the model that is registered with your ModelAdmin, most likely an instance of a `Person` model in this case

Comment: Thanks, and yes it is clear though but how does this object get passed into this method?

Comment: The list of results is iterated over and the method is called and displayed?

Comment: Ok, I iterated over your comments for few times, then used `print(obj)` in this method, referred to this: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py, and finally thanks for helping me to understand this. :-)